# Dark spots and lines showing up on render, GPU vs CPU?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, artifacts

I've been rendering out an animation for the past three days of a punching bag flying through a wall.  However, I noticed something kind of annoying. From frame 72 to 73, it seems like the smoke gets much darker and there is this weird line showing up on the wall.

[image]
[image]

I'm guessing that this may have happened in partially because I attempted running two instances of Blender, one using GPU and the other with CPU to try to make the rendering go faster, and I'm pretty sure that the frames that have the dark spots on them were rendered with the CPU, but I don't believe all of them were. Any ideas why this may have happened? I don't believe there are any values animated (that would cause something like this to happen), and both the physics and the smoke are baked.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, man, this looks weird... Last time I tried CPU/GPU combined the difference in lightning and grain between the images was clearly visible and also more random (not just a stripe, more of a irregular checkered pattern). Have you tried to render this single frame out only on CPU or GPU again?

Comment: @metaphor_set I rendered those frames again except with the GPU and it fixed the problem. Doesn't make any sense. Any ideas as to why this happened?